# Is it possible to change camera settings of an app on android emulator?

Tags: applications, settings

I am using Nox Android Emulator and i have a question about if i can change default camera settings of an app, i have uninstalled stock camera app by android terminal but this app still uses to default camera and don't ask for camera preferences.

Answer (score 0):

However it depends on the emulator I personally recommend bluestakes4 it also have an option for default apps and supports almost everything

Comment: i thought that it depends on apps, like an another app asks for which camera do i want to use, but an another one doesn't even ask and just use default camera app. I am trying to change preferences of this app.